# Extjs : Toolbar inside a panel not resizing on Browser resize

Tags: extjs, resize, extjs4.1, toolbar, gridpanel

I have a toolbar and a grid within a Panel. On resize, the grid looks good. However the toolbar maintains its original dimensions and does not resize causing a few buttons to hide .
How do I rectify this?

```
{
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'center',
                layout: 'border',
                tbar:[
                    {

                        xtype: 'buttongroup',
                        region: 'center', 
                        items:  getToolBarButtons()      // method to add buttons to toolbar dynamically
                    }
                ],
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'tabpanel',
                        activeTab: 0,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        region: 'center',
                        disabled: 'true',
                        items:[
                            {
                                // grid 1
                                height : '80%',
                                width : '100%'
                            },
                            {
                                // grid 2
                                height : '80%',
                                width : '100%'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

**Edit**:

I replaced `tbar` with `dockedItems: [{ xtype:' toolbar' ...}]` . The toolbar doesn't get rendered at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ext.toolbar.Toolbar` can automatically transform overflowed toolbar buttons to menu with menu items. To allowed this automatic transformations you need to configure your `toolbar` component with config [`enableOverflow: true`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar-cfg-enableOverflow)

So instead of `tbar` config use:

```
dockedItems: [{
   xtype: 'toolbar',
   dock: 'top',
   enableOverflow: true,
   items: [
      {
          xtype: 'buttongroup',                 
          items:  getToolBarButtons()
      }
   ]
}]
```

Also consider dividing buttons to more buttongroups. If toolbar has more buttongroups ExtJS toolbar can handle overflow with better results.

Fiddle with live example: **http://sencha.com/#fiddle/2nd**

Comment: I tried `enableOverflow: true` for the `tbar` . I didn't see an overflow menu. Has the behavior got something to do with writing as `dockedItems` instead of `tbar` ?

Comment: Yes it has. With `tbar: []` you can define only items in toolbar, not toolbar config. So you should use complete definition with `dockedItems` as I show in the answer (as you can read in documentation `tbar` is just shorthand for `dockedItems: [{ xtype: 'toolbar', dock: 'top', ...` )

Comment: Referring to my earlier **edit** , I replaced `tbar` with `dockedItems: [{ xtype:' toolbar' ...}]` . The toolbar doesn't get rendered at all

Comment: I setup fiddle with live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2nd Layout is same as you have in your question. Toolbar is defined in `dockedItems` config and as you can see it is rendered and overflow managing is working.